# How to execute multiple command after double pipes in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I am writing a Korn shell script where I have a function like this

```
#!/bin/ksh
myfunc() {
    some_command1 || return 1
    some_command2 || return 1
    ...
}
```

In words, I put the double pipes followed by a return statement so that the function return immediately when a command fails.

But I also want that it prints some error messages before returning, I tried

```
#!/bin/ksh
myfunc() {
    some_command1 || echo "error while doing some_command1"; return 1
    some_command2 || echo "error while doing some_command2"; return 1
    ...
}
```

But it does not work, the first return statement always get executed no matter `some_command1` has succeeded or failed.

And

```
#!/bin/ksh
myfunc() {
    some_command1 || (echo "error while doing some_command1"; return 1)
    some_command2 || (echo "error while doing some_command2"; return 1)
    ...
}
```

also doesn't work, it seems it only return from sub processes not the function and `some_command2` get executed no matter `some_command1` has succeeded or failed.

Is there a way to group the statements `echo "error while doing some_command2"; return 1` such that they both get executed together only when  the preceding command fails.

Comment: `{ cmd1; cmd2; }` maybe?

Comment: I like the style of that function - get the exceptions out of the way first, and avoid nested ifs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The straightforward way is to use `{ ...; ...; }`, this combines the commands without creating a subshell.

```
some_command1 ||
    { echo "error while doing some_command1"; return 1; }
```

I do recommend to use stderr for error messages, though:

```
some_command1 ||
    { echo "error while doing some_command1" >& 2; return 1; }
```

And just because I can, I'll give you my secret shortcut:

```
some_command1 ||
    return 1 $(echo "error while doing some_command1" >& 2)
```

That last bit is unconventional, but still portable POSIX shell.

Comment: Somehow the solution #1 and #2 doesn't work for me, it acts like no curly braces exist and always execute `return 1`. But the #3 works like a charm.

Comment: Sorry I just figured out why solution #1 and #2 did not work for me, it's because I write it like this: `{echo "444"; return 1}` where no semicolon after the `return 1`. This make the return statement execute every time

Comment: @asinkxcoswt, the `{` and `}` **must** have whitespace around them. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping

Comment: @asinkxcoswt As Glenn says, `(...)` and `{ ... }` are not interchangeable, as the parentheses do *not* require any white space, and the curly braces do.
@glennjackman as always, thanks for the detail.